# R/ package C5.0/ are there known nonrecoverable failure conditions?

Tags: r, crash

I am testing preprocessing combinations. The script generates and loops 3200 versions of the original data (n=48, p=30) and evaluates their fitness for classification with `knn`, `svmRadial`, `svmPolynomial`, `randomForest`, `gbm` and `C5.0`. The training is done via Caret's `train` function.

The smallest data versions have 35 rows and 3 columns. The categorical target variable
has three classes with app. 40%/40%/20% distribution.

For some reasons C5.0 results in R crashing somewhere between versions 1900-2800. The training/ test data version that crashes R is different every time. Running the script
with all the other classifiers works well.

The code used for C5.0 is:

```
C50_model <- function(train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y){
tryCatch({
C50_fit <- train(train_x, train_y, tuneLength=tuning,    
method="C5.0",trControl=bootControl)
C50_pred <- as.character(predict(C50_fit, newdata=test_x))
C50_error <- round(ce(test_y, C50_pred),2)
return(list(C50_pred, C50_error))
}, error= function(e) return(list(NA, NA)) ) # close tryCatch
}
```

trControl:

```
bootControl <- trainControl(method = "boot", number = 1, p=0.67)
```

Session info is:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

C5.0 is:

```
C50_0.1.0-15
```

Are there any known conditions that result in R crashing with C5.0
or something I can do to help R recover to error message without crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C5.0 is relatively new, so it wouldn't surprise me if there was some kind of memory allocation bug that was cauing R to crash.  Without the dataset, it's hard to determine the cause but you can at least narrow down when the error is occurring by writing logging info.

Add `verboseIter = TRUE` to the `trainControl` options, and turn off buffered output (in the Misc menu in R GUI).